# Upload file to RDS Postgres Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I want to create custom Full Text Search dictionary with special stop words from `some_words.stop`. How to upload this file to my RDS instance by FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [cannot do this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=143920) with RDS.  Sorry

Comment: i have only one option - install PostgreSQL on my EC2?

Comment: If you wan to host on AWS, then I believe so, yes.